# How to generate that many numbered rows of a letter using nested for loops in java?

Tags: java, loops

I want to input a number using the scanner, which then generates that many numbered rows of the letter "A".

Sample input:

```
5
```

Sample output:

```
1:A
2:AA
3:AAA
4:AAAA
5:AAAAA
```

This was my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Nested{
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = keyboard.nextInt();
    String n = "";
    for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++){
        for (int y = 1; y <= num; y++){
            n+="A";
            System.out.println(x+":"+n);
        }
      }
   }
```

}

**This has to be done with nested for loops only**

This was my actual output, I have the "A"'s right but the numbers are not right:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because too broad

Comment: Because thats a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you should be using `System.out.print`, which does not print a newline at the end, to build out each line of letters:

```
for (int x=1; x <= num; x++) {
    System.out.print(x + ":");
    for (int y=1; y <= x; y++) {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This prints:

```
1:A
2:AA
3:AAA
4:AAAA
5:AAAAA
```

Also, the bounds of the inner loop should run from 1 until the value of the dummy variable in the outer loop.  This is how to control printing an increasing number of letters on each subsequent line.

Answer (score 1):

Build up the string in the inner loop and print in the outer

```
for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++) {
    String n = "";
    for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
        n += "A";
    }
    System.out.println(x + ":" + n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to break what you want into logical steps.

First, you want num lines, so you're going to have to loop from 1 to num, which you do with `for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++)`.

Next, on each line, you want to print the line number, as well as that many As.  Thankfully you have those values, the line number is just x, so you can `System.out.print(x + ":");`

To print x As, you need another loop, but you don't want to print `num` As on each line, you want as many As as the line number you're on, which again is x. Each time the inner loop runs you want to print a single A `System.out.print("A");`, then once that for loop is finished you need to print a newline `System.out.println("");`

You could also do as you were doing here and add an "A" to a string, but note that you'll want to print that string AFTER the loop that adds the A to the string, otherwise you'll print out everytime you add an A to the string, which is why in your attempt you have multiple prints per line #.  You'll also need to make sure the string is reset to "" after every print, otherwise you'll be adding too many "A"s.  I guess you could also only add one "A" to the string everytime, but then you wouldn't need the nested for loop and I guess that's a requirement of yours

Note the difference in `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`  -- the first simply prints whatever you want while the second prints what you want and then goes to a new line

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use stream api, if you want to write this more functional way.
Additionally you can use String.repeat(n) function, which returns your string copied n times.

```java
import java.util.stream.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    IntStream.range(1, n+1)
      .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + ": " + "A".repeat(i)));
  }
}
```